# Save a drop down menu using html

Tags: drop-down-menu, save, html-select

I tried to make an attendance list that you can change online (password protected so that only admins can change it (on Wordpress)). But I don't know how to make it save changes. (I don't know much about programming, just the very basics.)

So I came up with a list where you can mark the attendances, but when you visit the page later it hasn't saved the changes. I tried implementing a submit button but that doesn't help me either.

```
`<td class="select"><select>
<option value="present">Present</option>
<option value="late">Late</option>
<option value="absent">Absent</option>
<option value="excused">Excused</option>
</select></td>`
```

This is the drop down menu that i made, it gets repeated a lot (once for every member on every date).

How do you make it save the changes (I also tried to send the data to a different page, but i suppose i did it wrong cause that did not work either)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery and JavaScript to get this done. Please find the changes below.

**HTML -**

```
<td class="select"><select id="sel" onchange="func()">
<option value="present">Present</option>
<option value="late">Late</option>
<option value="absent">Absent</option>
<option value="excused">Excused</option>
</select></td>
```

**JavaScript -**

```
<script>
function func(){
let attendence = $("#sel option:selected").val();
}
</script>
```

You will get the desired value in *attendence* and now you can use **php** or **AJAX** to save the data to your database.

Comment: How do I use Php to save the data to my database?

Comment: Making custom changes in a Wordpress site might be tricky. This should help you out - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#INSERT_rows

Comment: To add custom php to your wordpress site you can use Code Snippets plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/